# OR condition not returning data

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> SELECT MIN(elevation_in_meters) as AE,common_name
    -> FROM paplants
    -> WHERE common_name="common lilac"
    -> OR common_name="eastern redbud"
    -> OR common_name="rugosa rose";
```

I'm only getting data for 'common lilac' but i should also be getting data for 'eastern redbud' and 'rugosa rose'

Comment: you can also use the [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) clause

Answer (score 0):

Add `GROUP BY common_name`.  That should help.